# Keras Tensorflow works well in training and test, but predict same class for all inputs in final dataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, classification, softmax

I'm having trouble using Tensorflow to solve a classification problem

I have a dataset with 259,514 rows, classified into the following groups:

```
Groups:

[0,1)       - 171.646 rowns
[1,55)      - 17.262  rowns
[55,105)    - 17.320  rowns
[105,170)   - 17.392  rowns
[170,285)   - 18092   rowns
[285, Inf]  - 17802   rowns
```

I tried to balance the data leaving only about 18,000 rows for each group.

The data were then divided into 70,869 training lines and 34,907 test lines.

The network was trained with 20 epochs, the acuracy was 0.54831, when generating the matrix of confusion (Train x Test) I obtained the following result:

```
labels=["[0,1)", "[1,55)","[55,105)", "[105,170)", "[170,285)","[285, Inf]"])

array([[5019,  215,   78,  182,  189,  136],
       [ 224, 3260,  807,  522,  331,  546],
       [ 258, 1076, 2236,  926,  504,  744],
       [ 273,  492,  592, 2534,  965,  997],
       [ 238,  375,  394,  819, 2555, 1549],
       [ 134,  249,  347,  418,  821, 3902]])
```

It seems OK to me.

But when I finally try to predict my data, I have all the lines in a single group:

```
ix
Y_pred
[1,55)                3
[105,170)             3
[170,285)             8
[285, Inf]            788286
```

I've already tried:

- Train the network with the entire DataSet
- Do not normalize data
- Normalize data with StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler, RobutsScaler
- Train the model for 500 epochs
- Add or remove layers and neurons from the network

  I really do not know what might be causing this, can anyone help me?

```py
    from google.colab import drive
    drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
    
    #Bibliotecas
    import keras
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
    from keras.optimizers import SGD
    
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
    from keras.utils import np_utils
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
    from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
    from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn import preprocessing
    
    #Equili
    dataset =  dataset.groupby('vl_baixa_group', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(min(len(x), 18000)))
    dataset.groupby(['vl_baixa_group']).count()
    
    
    ##Normalize
    from sklearn import preprocessing
    x = dataset.select_dtypes(include='int64')
    StandardScaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
    x_scaled = StandardScaler.fit_transform(x)
    
    x_new = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled, columns=x.columns, index=x.index)
    dataset_norm = pd.concat([x_new,dataset.select_dtypes(include='category')], join="inner", axis=1)
    
    #Dumyes
    dataset_norm = pd.get_dummies(dataset_norm,  columns= (dataset_norm.select_dtypes(include='category')).columns.difference(['vl_baixa_group',]))
      
    
    #DataFrame Numpy
    dataframe = dataset_norm.to_numpy()
    
    #Y
    Y = dataframe[:,dataset_norm.columns.get_loc("vl_baixa_group")]
    
    encoder = LabelEncoder()
    encoder.fit(Y)
    encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
    Y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)
    
    #X
    X = dataframe[:,(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45)]
    
    #Z
    Z = (dataset_norm.index).to_numpy()
    
    
    
    # seed for reproducing same results
    seed = 9
    np.random.seed(seed)
    
    # split the data into training (67%) and testing (33%)
    (X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test, Z_train, Z_test) = train_test_split(X, Y, Z, test_size=0.33, random_state=seed)
    
    #Z_test.shape
    
    unique_elements, counts_elements = np.unique(encoder.inverse_transform(np.argmax( Y_test ,axis=1)) , return_counts=True)
    print("Frequency of unique values of the said array:")
    print(np.asarray((unique_elements, counts_elements)))
    
    #NetWork
    
    from keras.callbacks import * 
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow import keras
    
    #Check Point
    checkpoint_path = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Models/2019_05_07_keras_tensor_deacts/training_cp/cp_epochs2:{epoch:03d}-val_acc:{val_acc:.3f}.ckpt"
    checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
    
    # Create checkpoint callback
    cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path,
                                                     save_best_only=True,
                                                     monitor='val_acc',
                                                     mode='max',
                                                     verbose=1)
    
    # create the model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=45, init='random_normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(32, init='random_normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(6,  init='random_normal', activation='softmax'))
    
    # compile the model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    #Fiting
    # fit the model
    history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), nb_epoch=20, batch_size=5, verbose=1, callbacks = [cp_callback])
    
    # evaluate the model
    scores = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
    print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
    
    #Salvando Modelo
    model.save('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Models/2019_05_07_keras_tensor_deacts/model.h5')
    
    
    
    #Confusion Matrix
    
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
    cm = confusion_matrix( encoder.inverse_transform(np.argmax( Y_test ,axis=1)) 
                          ,encoder.inverse_transform(np.argmax( y_pred ,axis=1))
                          ,labels=["[0,1)", "[1,55)","[55,105)", "[105,170)", "[170,285)","[285, Inf]"])
    cm
    
    
    
    #------ Predict real Data
    
    #Normalize
    from sklearn import preprocessing
    x_pred = dataset_pred.select_dtypes(include='int64')
    x_scaled_pred = StandardScaler.transform(x_pred)
    
    x_new_pred = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled_pred, columns=x_pred.columns, index=x_pred.index)
    dataset_norm_pred = pd.concat([x_new_pred,dataset_pred.select_dtypes(include='category')], join="inner", axis=1)
    
    dataset_norm_pred.head()
    
    # Dumyes
      dataset_norm_pred = pd.get_dummies(dataset_norm_pred,  columns= (dataset_norm_pred.select_dtypes(include='category')).columns.difference(['vl_baixa_group',]))
    
    dataset_norm_pred.describe()
    
    dataset_norm.describe()
    
    #  DataFrame Numpy
    dataframe_pred = dataset_norm_pred.to_numpy()
    
    # X
    X_Pred = dataframe_pred[:,(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44)]
    
    # Z
    Z_Pred = (dataset_norm_pred.index).to_numpy()
    
    pred = model.predict(X_Pred)
    
    pred
    
    pred_t = np.column_stack((Z_Pred
                               ,encoder.inverse_transform(np.argmax( pred ,axis=1))))
    
    other_pred = pd.DataFrame(data=pred_t[1:,0:],    # values
                 index=pred_t[1:,0],    # 1st column as index
                 columns=['ix','Y_pred']
                )  # 1st row as the column names
    
    #other_pred.head()
    
    other_pred.groupby(['Y_pred']).count()
```

Comment: You are normalizing the prediction(`x_scaled_pred`) data and training(`x_scaled`) data separately. Both dataset should be scaled using common parameters.

Comment: Mitiku, thanks for the reply :)

But when I normalize the training data I use x_scaled = StandardScaler.fit_transform (x) (I use this for training and testing), the 'fit' method should create the normalization paramets.

In the prediction data, I use x_scaled_pred = StandardScaler.transform (x_pred) (there is no 'fit' here) it should inherit the parametos created in the training base.

x_scaled = fit_transform (x)
x_scaled_pred = transform (x_pred) - I hope it normalizes as generated in the previous fit method.

Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the dataset so that we can try reproducing the error and help you in resolving the issue.